# How to set smart search box results URL relatively based on url via macro?

Tags: kentico

Given the following page structure in Kentico v7:

- Root

  - Alpha

    - One

      - Search
    - Two
  - Bravo

    - One

      - Search
    - Two
  - Charlie
  - Delta
  - Echo

Pages `Alpha` and `Bravo` (and their children) share the same template. On that template is a search box web part. I would like to set the search results URL to be either:

`/Alpha/One/Search/` or `/Bravo/One/Search` depending under which node the control is rendered. It seems that the only way I can realistically accomplish this is via a macro in the search box web part's properties.

Question: How would you write a macro to dynamically set this property based on it's parent path?

Here is what I currently have but it doesn't seem to work:

```
/{%Split(CurrentPageInfo.DocumentURLPath, '/')[0]#%}/one/search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using macros is a correct approach in this case.

Try the following one (V7):

```
~/{% CurrentDocument.NodeAliasPath.Split("/")[1]#%}/one/search
```

V8:

```
~/{% Split(CurrentDocument.NodeAliasPath, "/", true)[0]#%}/one/search
```

Comment: gracias amigo that is the syntax I was struggling to find.